# How to select a Node by it's atrribute name and get it's child node in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

Here is my XML code(module.xml)

```
<module code="ECSE502">
  <code>ECSE502</code>
  <name>Algorithms and Data structures</name>
  <semester>1</semester>
  <prerequisites>none</prerequisites>
  <lslot>0</lslot>
  <tslot>1</tslot>
  <description>all about algorythms and data structers</description>
</module>
<module code="EIGA501">
  <code>EIGA501</code>
  <name>3D Grapgics I</name>
  <semester>1</semester>
  <prerequisites>none</prerequisites>
  <lslot>2</lslot>
  <tslot>3</tslot>
  <description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</description>
</module>
```

According to the above xml code, I need to get the  set by only giving ECSE502 as the input.
After selecting the required node I need to get its child node's values also(name, semester,etc.).
In the XML file there are 20 nodes. this is only the 1st 2 nodes.

I tried this so far

```
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("modules.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);

        foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes)
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

wrap your xml in a unique root node i.e

```
<modules>
   <module code...
       ..
   </module>
   <module code...
</modules>
```

and then

```
string text="ECSE502";

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("physical path to module.xml"); 

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("modules/module[@code='"+text+"']");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string code = xn.SelectSingleNode("code").innerText;
    string name=  xn.SelectSingleNode("name").innerText;
    //and similarly find other inner nodes
}
```

Comment: not worked. and what does it do in line,
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/module[@code='"+text+"']");

Comment: try wrapping your modules in a root tag.i.e <Modules><module.. and see the update

Comment: it finds only those module node which have their code attribute as the text

Comment: yeh it's working. But all the data is in one line as,
ECSE502Algorithms and Data structures1none01
how can I divide them according to there nodes

Comment: please check this too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700848/read-from-a-xml-file-to-an-array-node-by-node-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), assume in here the code returns the list of anonymous objects, but you can explicitly define your own class if you want:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("yourpathfile");
var result = xDoc.Descendants("module")
            .Where(x => (string) x.Element("code") == "ECSE502")
            .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 Name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                                 //.....
                             });
```

Comment: @Ravindu: try this way also :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it after creating a root node in your xml with below code

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\data\rvyas\Projects\Client\module.xml");


string code = "ECSE502";
    var result = xdoc.Descendants("module")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("code") == code)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                    Code = (string)x.Element("code"),
                    semester = (string)x.Element("semester"),
                    prerequisites = (string)x.Element("prerequisites"),
                    lslot = (string)x.Element("lslot"),
                    tslot = (string)x.Element("tslot")

                }).ToList();
```

You XML should be like:

```
<root>
<module code="ECSE502">
  <code>ECSE502</code>
  <name>Algorithms and Data structures</name>
  <semester>1</semester>
  <prerequisites>none</prerequisites>
  <lslot>0</lslot>
  <tslot>1</tslot>
  <description>all about algorythms and data structers</description>
</module>
<module code="EIGA501">
  <code>EIGA501</code>
  <name>3D Grapgics I</name>
  <semester>1</semester>
  <prerequisites>none</prerequisites>
  <lslot>2</lslot>
  <tslot>3</tslot>
  <description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</description>
</module>
</root>
```