# Read from a XML file to an Array node by node in C#

Tags: c#, xml

The XML file is like this,There are about 20 Nodes(modules) like this.

```
<list>
<module code="ECSE502">
<code>ECSE502</code>
<name>Algorithms and Data structures</name>
<semester>1</semester>
<prerequisites>none</prerequisites>
<lslot>0</lslot>
<tslot>1</tslot>
<description>all about algorythms and data structers with totorials and inclass tests</description>
</module>    
</list>
```

I did the following code. But when I debugged it it even didn't went inside to foreach function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ModuleEnrolmentCW
{
    class XMLRead
    {

        public string[] writeToXML(string s)
        {
            string text = s;           
            string[] arr = new string[6];

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("modules.xml");

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("list/module[@code='" + text + "']");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                arr[0] = xn.SelectSingleNode("code").InnerText;
                arr[1] = xn.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
                arr[2] = xn.SelectSingleNode("semester").InnerText;
                arr[3] = xn.SelectSingleNode("prerequisites").InnerText;
                arr[4] = xn.SelectSingleNode("lslot").InnerText;
                arr[5] = xn.SelectSingleNode("tslot").InnerText;                            
            }

            return arr;
        }


    }
}
```

Please tell me where is the wrong??

Here is the rest of the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ModuleEnrolmentCW
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string selected;
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XMLRead x = new XMLRead();
            selected = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            string[] arr2 = x.writeToXML(selected);

            label11.Text = arr2[0];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Do you pass correct code to `writeToXML`?

Comment: Your code is working have you test the `text` value to be a valid `code`

Comment: Debug your application, put a breakpoint after `xml.Load` and confirm the values of `text` and `xml`.

Comment: text's value is a string. It passes correct

Comment: Does the XML node `module code=` case match with the case in `listbox1.SelectedItem` after casting to `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I was passing a wrong value to writeToXML method. Insted of passing code, I have passed name

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("list/module[@code='" + text + "']");
```

should read:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("list/module"); //Does not answer full scope of the question
```

**Edit following a reread of the question:**

The OP's code works fine in my tests. Either the file path is not correct, or the the `string s` passed into `text` matches the case of the `Code` value by which you are reading the nodes.

The `SelectNodes` `XPath` as you have it is case sensitive.

You appear to be working with XPath V1.0 which doesn't appear to support out of the box case insensitivity if that's a issue. See this link for a way to perform case insensitive XPath searches: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shjin/archive/2005/07/22/442025.aspx

See also this link: [case-insensitive matching in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath)

Comment: This will work for this isolated example but I think it's pretty clear he wants to be able to specify modules by their `code` attribute (given that that's the only use of the string parameter)...

Comment: How can you pass the `Code` value for which he wants to read the nodes

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are specifying correct path for your xml file.

It is working for me.

[image]

Comment: I did ,
xml.Load(@"D:\Modules.xml");
and put the file in my D partition.NOT working

Comment: I have tested it on my machine it is working. Try to debug your code. Their must be some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, **if the input is really the one you shown**, and `s` **point to an actual present code**. Since you are pointing the file by a relative path, ensure you are loading the file you really expect.